# A (Simple) Arithmetic puzzle

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

I'm hoping this one was not posted here already, tried to search a bit and didn't find it. It's a really nice brain teaser:

> Add arithmetic operators (plus, minus, times, divide) to make the following expression
>   true:
>
> 3 1 3 6 = 8.
>
> You can use any parentheses you’d like.

Comment: https://www.google.fr/search?q=3+1+3+6+%3D+8.&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=R0LJV8PCBszI8gelpoAw#safe=off&q=3+1+3+6+%3D+8

Comment: @IAmInPLS Wow, a simple google search. I probably shouldn't have answered this.

Comment: Not saying I used google, I'm just saying it was probably too easy and just a math problem?

Comment: Deleting answer, I got too excited

Comment: @bg6471, if I were you. I would undelete the answer. Even if the question proves to be off-topic, your answer is totally valid.

Comment: Should've switched out the numbers, this way googling solved it. A shame

Comment: @Vucko if it makes you feel better, I solved it using the raw power of my brain and notepad.exe because I didn't have a pen and paper

Comment: If you had allowed powers then a simple one would have been $$3-1^3+6=8.$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is below

> (3 + 1)/3 * 6

Answer (score 2):

The solution is,

> (3+1)/3*6 = 8

or

> (3+1)/(3/6) = 8

Answer (score 1):

I think

> (3+1)/3*6=8

works fine